# Last n words from a string in bash

Tags: string, bash

I have a string containing many (the total number varies) words, and I need to get last 10 of them. How do I do it? I'm looking at awk, grep and cut but nothing really comes to mind.

An example (although it seems to me that the question is clear):

```
aaa bda fdkfj fds fsd ... dsad dsas dsad zrthd shshh
```

I want the last 10 words of this string.

Again, the total number of words in the initial string isn't defined.

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: Reverse it then take then 10 first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're trying to find words or characters at the last, it's better to use end of the line anchor `$` in your regex.

```
$ echo "aaa bda fdkfj fds fsd bar dsad dsas dsad zrthd shshh" | grep -o '[^[:space:]]\+\([[:space:]]\+[^[:space:]]\+\)\{9\} *$'
bda fdkfj fds fsd bar dsad dsas dsad zrthd shshh
```

You could use the same regex in sed also.

**OR**

```
$ echo "aaa bda fdkfj fds fsd bar dsad dsas dsad zrthd shshh" | grep -oP '\S+(?:\s+\S+){9} *$'
bda fdkfj fds fsd bar dsad dsas dsad zrthd shshh
```

Answer (score 5):

Just play with `tr`, `tail` and `xargs`:

```
$ echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" | tr ' ' '\n' | tail -5 | xargs -n5
6 7 8 9 10
```

This prints the words one in every line, so that `tail` gets the desired amount of them. Then, `xargs` "remerges" them in the same line.

You can also set awk's `NF` to the value you want after reversing the text:

```
$ echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" | rev | awk '{NF=5}1' | rev
6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 2):

In `awk`, the builtin variable NF is set to the number of fields (which are by default words) on each line. So you can:

```
echo "${STRING}" | awk '{
    for (i = NF - 9; i <= NF; i++) {printf "%s ", $i}
    printf "\n"
}'
```

assuming that you always have at least 10 words on the line. If not, you can add extra checks for that. And do something more if you don't want the extra space at the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

You want shell? This is **pure shell**. No `awk`, no `cut`, no `sed`, no `perl`. You can't get more sell than this. (Okay, I do use `wc` which is a utility and not part of Bash shell, but everything else is part of Bash).

```
FOO="one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen"
set $FOO
((shift=$(wc -w<<<$FOO)-10))
shift $shift
echo $*
```

- The `set` sets the positional parameters. (The `$1`, `$2`, etc. in command line arguments).
- The `$(wc -w<<<$FOO)` finds the number of parameters.
- I subtract that number from `10`, and get the number of parameters greater than ten. I set this to `$shift`
- I then shift `$shift` parameters. This leaves the last ten parameters which I echo.

---

> You don't really need wc. $# expands to the number of positional parameters set. –  gniourf_gniourf

Oh, I forgot about that. Now, we have a **pure Bash** answer:

```
FOO='one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen'
set $FOO
((shift=$#-10))
shift $shift
echo $*
```

Comment: This is subject to pathname expansion! `FOO='* one two [abc]*'`. Not good.

Comment: You don't really need `wc`. `$#` expands to the number of positional parameters set.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Ah! That's what I was missing. You're right. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical, pure Bash way of doing this is to use `read`:

```
string='one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen forty two'
read -r -d '' -a array < <(printf '%s\0' "$string")
# Print only ten last words:
printf '%s\n' "${array[*]: -10}"
```

If there are less than 10 words, the last expansion fails, but this can be easily fixed:

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[*]:${#array[@]}<10?0:-10}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your string:

```
string="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
```

The last four words by using a pure Bash/Shell one-liner:

```
echo ${string/${string% * * * *} /}
```

Repeat or remove  `*` to fetch more or less words.

**Explanation**
We use the [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) `${parameter/pattern/string}` to replace x words by nothing. And as the pattern `${str% * * * *}`  returns everything in front of the last 4 words it removes the leading `Lorem` from our string.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $string | perl -lanE 'say join " ", @F[-10..-1]'
```